# What is the word for this?

Tags: single-word-requests

A person who is really interested in knowing another private life or business.

Many thanks

Comment: "Nosy", for starters.  Could be a voyeur.

Answer (score 1):

I would call that person a **busybody**.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/busybody

"My aunt is a very annoying busybody.  She's always sticking her nose into my marriage and giving me unsolicited advice."

Answer (score 0):

Another option is **sticky beak** (n.), which is sometimes also used as verb. May also be hyphenated, or written as one word.